# Make a function in Scheme to substract two lists

Tags: list, function, scheme

I am quite new with Scheme and with StackOverflow as well!
So, for the first contact I would like to do something simple and easy in Scheme.
I want to define a function that substracts the elements of the introduced list.

For example, the inputs should be: (sub '(4 12 6) '(0 6 3))
And the output should be: (4 6 3)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll need is to have a base case where you check if either list is empty and evaluate it to the empty list or you make a pair with the calculation of the first element of each list and the recursion for the rest of both lists. Basically you end up with:

```
(cons (- 4 0) (cons (- 12 6) (cons (- 6 3) '()))) ; ==> (4 6 3)
```

As an example of a recursive list processing function here is one that negates all elements:

```
(define (negate-list lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (- (car lst)) 
            (negate-list (cdr lst)))))

(negate-list '(1 2 3 4)) ; ==> (-1 -2 -3 -4)
```

Now there are even more fancy ways to do this. Eg,. you can use tail recursion:

```
(define (negate-list lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (acc '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        (reverse acc)
        (loop (cdr lst)
              (cons (- (car lst)) acc)))))
```

You can use `map`:

```
(define (negate-list lst)
  (map - lst))
```

So there you go. you're half way there.

Comment: Hello Sylwester,

Thank you very much for the answer. It has been very helpful for me.

I have another question:

WHY DOES THIS WORK?:

     (define (negate-list lst lst2)
       (map - lst lst2))

     (negate-list '(11 12 13 14)'(1 2 3 4))


AND THIS DOESN'T?:

     (define (sub-one lst)
       (map - lst 1))

     (sub-one '(11 12 13 14))

How could I define an easy function to substarct one from a given list?

Thank you

Comment: @JackGreen `map`  second to n arguments need to be lists since it applies the procedure the the first element of each of the arguments. What is `(car 1)` or `(cdr 1)`? You can do this: `(map (lambda (e) (- e 1)) '(11 12 13 14)) ;==> (10 11 12 13)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sylwester!! It really helps. One more enquery, why it doesn't work?:(define (next lst))
(map (lambda (e) (+ e 1))

(next '(1 2 3 4)). The output should be (2 3 4 5)

Comment: @JackGreen The reason why it doesn't work is because you have `define` but your `map` expression is outside it. Unlike my comment you don't have any list arguments in your `map`

Comment: I have been working for hours but I can't make this work: (define (next lst)
(map (lambda (lst) (+ lst 1)))) It is neither working and I don't know how to fix it... Any help, please.

Comment: @JackGreen Look at my last example, you see I pass a function **and** a list. You just pass just a function. In your fucntion you name the number `lst` which is strange since `lst` is common name for a list argument. I used `e` (as in **e**lement) but `i` (**i**nteger) or `n` (**n**umber) are very common unless you give it a specific name like `vat`, `element-count`, `alarms-per-hour`... Of course what arguments are named is just naming convention but using `lst` will give programmers the wrong idea.